# AJAX cascading dropdownlist not populating

Tags: asp.net, mysql, vb.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm following the tutorial [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/ajax-control-toolkit/cascadingdropdown/using-cascadingdropdown-with-a-database-vb) to try to implement cascading drop down lists using the AJAX toolkit in VS2012, however, I am using MySQL as my database instead. I created a webservice (as the tutorial describes - seen below),

```
<WebMethod()>
Public Function GetComplex(ByVal knownCategoryValues As String, ByVal category As String) As CascadingDropDownNameValue()
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; database=lockout; User ID=root; Pwd=123let?")
    conn.Open()
    Dim comm As New MySqlCommand("SELECT complex_id, complex_name FROM complex ORDER BY complex_name", conn)
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader()
    Dim l As New List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue)
    While (dr.Read())
        l.Add(New CascadingDropDownNameValue(dr("complex_name").ToString(), dr("complex_id").ToString()))
    End While
    conn.Close()
    Return l.ToArray()
End Function
```

and I am able to connect to my database and invoke my function. Invoking the function returns the following in my web browser:

```
<ArrayOfCascadingDropDownNameValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
 <CascadingDropDownNameValue>
  <name>14 Line</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <isDefaultValue>false</isDefaultValue>
 </CascadingDropDownNameValue>
 <CascadingDropDownNameValue>
  <name>16 Line</name>
  <value>2</value>
  <isDefaultValue>false</isDefaultValue>
 </CascadingDropDownNameValue>
 <CascadingDropDownNameValue>
  <name>Converting</name>
  <value>3</value>
  <isDefaultValue>false</isDefaultValue>
 </CascadingDropDownNameValue>
 <CascadingDropDownNameValue>
  <name>F&E</name>
  <value>4</value>
  <isDefaultValue>false</isDefaultValue>
 </CascadingDropDownNameValue>
 <CascadingDropDownNameValue>
  <name>Water Quality</name>
  <value>5</value>
  <isDefaultValue>false</isDefaultValue>
 </CascadingDropDownNameValue>
</ArrayOfCascadingDropDownNameValue>
```

I can see that I am generating the necessary array, but for some reason, the array does not appear in my drop down list and I'm not sure why. It looks as though I have covered everything in the tutorial, but I just can't seem to get it to work. Shown below is my .aspx file.

```
<%@ Page Title="LockoutNew" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LockoutNew.aspx.vb" Inherits="Lockout.LockoutNew" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="ajaxToolkit" %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

<div>
    Complex: <asp:DropDownList ID="ComplexList" runat="server" /><br />
   <!-- Machine: <asp:DropDownList ID="MachineList" runat="server" /><br /> -->
</div>

<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="ccd1" runat="server" 
    ServicePath="lockoutService.asmx" ServiceMethod="GetComplex" 
    TargetControlID="ComplexList" Category="Complex" 
    PromptText="Select Complex" />

<!-- <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="ccd2" runat="server" 
    ServicePath="lockoutService.asmx.vb" ServiceMethod="GetMachine" 
    TargetControlID="MachineList" ParentControlID="ComplexList" 
    Category="Machine" 
    PromptText="Select Machine" /> -->

</asp:Content>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: Sometimes I've seen other people have issues when hosting it in a WebService instead of just the code-behind.  What happens if you move the method to your VB code-behind, updating your `ServicePath` accordingly?

Comment: And you also look like you may be missing the `<ScriptService()>` attribute at the top of the function declaration.

Comment: I will need to do some research on code-behind before I can get back to you on that (VB novice here). The ScriptService attribute is located on the Site.Master, so I would think that the webpage posted above would receive the attribute as well?

Comment: Not necessarily.  The vb code behind is the file named .aspx.vb

Answer (score 0):

I had the same exact issue.
The thing is that when building cascading logic u need to know that the first element is different from the rest.
The first in the chain element does not have any parameters to pass to the method !
Thus your method for the first drop down list must contain no parameters  :

```
Public Function GetComplex() As CascadingDropDownNameValue()
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection("Server=localhost; database=lockout; User ID=root; Pwd=123let?")
    conn.Open()
    Dim comm As New MySqlCommand("SELECT complex_id, complex_name FROM complex ORDER BY complex_name", conn)
    Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = comm.ExecuteReader()
    Dim l As New List(Of CascadingDropDownNameValue)

    While (dr.Read())
        l.Add(New CascadingDropDownNameValue(dr("complex_name").ToString(), dr("complex_id").ToString()))
    End While

    conn.Close()
    Return l.ToArray()
End Function
```